# SwipeRefresh Layout not working with custom empty listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment, empty-list, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to add a `SwipeRefreshLayout` layout in one of my fragment.
Everything works as expected when the list contain some elements.

The problem is when my list is empty. I have a `ViewStub` showing up when the list doesn't contain any item, and at that point my `OnRefreshListener` is never triggered.

Here is my ListFragment xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRenewals"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <ViewStub
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout="@layout/empty_renewal"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And the layout that I load in the ViewStub:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_warning"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_renewal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/refresh_for_new"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So is there a way I can get the swipe gesture to trigger the refresh when the list is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently writing the problem down helped.

I solved my problem by encapsulating my ViewStub Layout in a ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_warning"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_renewal"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/refresh_for_new"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```